# Migrated private ssh key not detected

Tags: ssh

I have moved my private key to a new PC. 
Permissions are correct (0600)
However, ssh user@server doesn't use the migrated key
I tried creating the config file for that host, but still nothing

The key works if referenced directly via ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@server

Can't seem to find any useful info on migrating private keys between computers (except: just copy)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your [`~/.ssh/config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) on your old computer, you should have a line similar to the one below,

```
Host server
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This is what tells `ssh` to use the key without having to specify it manually.

Comment: Done that, didn't work. In the end, adding Host * was the solution. But the computer where I created the key didn't have the config file

Comment: That's because the asterisk means for any host. So if you were connecting to github.com it would be `Host github.com`.

Comment: The problem was that ssh didn't use my key for any connections (computer where I generated the key doesn't have the **config** file, but ssh uses the only available key. On the new pc, I had to use `Host *`

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
Host *
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

resolved the issue